# Why does this naive prime-number algorithm fail?

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I am attempting to implement [this "find the nth prime number" algorithm](http://www.paul-scott.com/nth-prime.php) in Ruby 2.1.

I've tagged it 'algorithm' as well because I think the question is language-agnostic, and that the Ruby code written is simple enough to read even if you're unfamiliar. I've used descriptive variable names to help it.

1. Iterate over the whole number system, ignoring even numbers greater than 2 (2, 3, 5, 7, …)
2. For each integer, p, check if p is prime:

   1. Iterate over the primes already found which are less than the square-root of p
   2. For each prime in this set, f, check to see if it is a factor of p:
      i. If f divides p then p is non-prime. Continue from 2 for the next p.
   3. If no factors are found, p is prime. Continue to 3.
3. If p is not the nth prime we have found, add it to the list of primes. Continue from 2 for the next p.
4. Otherwise, p is the nth prime we have found and we should return it.

Sounds simple enough. So I write my method (function):

```
    def nth_prime(n)
        primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]

        primes[-1].upto(Float::INFINITY) do |p|
            return primes[n-1] if primes.length >= n-1
            possible_prime = true
            primes_to_check = primes.select{|x|x<=Math.sqrt(p)}
            primes_to_check.each do |f|
                if f%p==0
                    possible_prime = false
                    break
                end
            end
            primes << p if possible_prime
        end
    end
```

The intent is to say `nth_prime(10)` and get the 10th prime number.

To explain my logic:

I start with a list of known primes, since the algorithm requires that. I list the first ten.

Then I iterate over the entire number system. `(primes[-1]+2).upto(Float::Infinity) do |p|` will offer each number up from the last known prime plus two (since +1 will result in an even number and evens over 2 cannot be prime) to infinity to the indented block as `p`. I have not skipped even numbers and have

The first thing I do is return the *n*th prime number if the list of known primes is already at least *n* elements long. This works for the known values -- if you ask for the 5th, you'll get 11 as a result.

Then I set a flag, `possible_prime`, to `true`. This indicates that nothing has proved it to be *not* a prime yet. I'm going to do some tests and if it survives those without the flag being changed to `false`, then `p` is proven to be prime and is appended to the known-primes array. Eventually that array will be as long as *n* and return the nth value.

I create an array, `primes_to_check`, containing all known primes <= the square root of p. Each one gets tested in turn as `f`.

**If f can cleanly divide p**, I know that p is not prime, so I change the flag to `false`, and `break`, which brings us out of the primes-to-check loop and back in the upto-infinity loop. There's only one statement left in that loop, the one that appends to the known-primes array if the flag is true, which it isn't so we restart the loop with the next number.

**If no `f`s can cleanly divide p** then p must be prime, which means it survives to the end of the primes-to-check loop with the flag still set to true, and reaches the final 'append p to known primes' statement.

Eventually this will make the `primes` array sufficiently longer to answer the question "What is the nth prime?".

## Problem

Asking for the 10th prime does get me 29, the last prime I pre-supplied. But asking for 11 gets `nil`, or no value. I've gone over the code a hundred times and can't imagine a case in which no value gets returned.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
return primes[n-1] if primes.length >= n-1
```

For `primes` to have an element at index `n-1`, it must have length at least `n`.

```
if f%p==0
```

This checks whether a known prime is divisible by the candidate, not whether the candidate is divisible by a known prime.

```
primes[-1].upto(Float::INFINITY) do |p|
```

This starts the loop at a prime already in the list (29). 29 is correctly found to be prime, so it is added to the list again. You'll want to start the loop at a number after 29.

Comment: Hmm. Good catch, I think I was thinking zero-indexed or something there. But changing it to `n` rather than `n-1` introduces a new bug: the 11th prime returns the 10th, and and every additional number just returns the next integer in line, not the next prime.

Comment: @GreenTriangle: Found some more bugs. If there are still more, try to find them yourself before asking again.

Answer (score 0):

```
Algorithm for testing prime no.s:
1)Input num
2)counter= n-1
3)repeat 
4)remainder = num%counter
5)if rem=0 then
6)broadcast not a prime.no and stop
7)change counter by -1
8)until counter = 1
9)say its a prime and stop
```

Comment: How does this answer `What have I done wrong?`? Does this `find the nth prime number`? Is it as efficient as, say, starting from 2 and going upwards?

Comment: Yes when you enter a number, it tells you whether it is a prime or not.

Comment: The nth prime number is something else: if you enter 5, you shouldn't answer true (or false), 2, 3, 5, 7, or 9, but `11`, as it is the fifth prime number. (Anyway, GreenTriangle's question still reads `What have I done wrong?`)